# qBitTorrent does not start minimized to tray

Tags: startup-applications, qbittorrent

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. After installing qbittorrent I checked the option to start minimized and minimize qbittorrent to notification area. But when I put it in the startup applications it starts in the default window which is not the expected behaviour. How can I make it launch minimized when launching manually or from startup.

Comment: How did you install qbittorrent?

Answer (score 0):

Add `User` and `Group` fields to your gdm3 config, see [this documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#:%7E:text=the%20user%20value.-,User,GDM%20User%20And%20Group%22%20section%20of%20this%20document%20for%20more%20information.,-5.4.3.%E2%80%83Debug:%7E:text=the%20user%20value.-,User,-User%3Dgdm) ([here's a picture of the config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygd2F.png)). Noticed that qBittorrent started minimized to tray when logging in normally, but didn't when using [automatic login](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en). Adding these fields fixed it.